# C помощью Linq не могу получить правильную выборку

Tags: c#, запрос, linq

Есть следующая задача. Нужно выбрать из данной таблицы следующее:

1. Общие настройки для первого и второго типа системы, сделал так:

   ```
   var general =
       dtSettings.AsEnumerable()
       .Where(
           r =>
               r.Field<bool>("forEachRow") == false && r.Field<string>("delimiter") == string.Empty &&
              (r.Field<int>("out_in_block") == 1 || r.Field<int>("out_in_block") == 2));
   ```
2. Выбрать для типа блока 1. Все поля с out_in_block=1 и минус выборка из первого примера. Я пытался сделать, что-то в обратную сторону делая условие вроде:

   ```
   var vnytrblock = dtSettings.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<int>("out_in_block") == 1).
           Where(rs => (rs.Field<bool>("forEachRow") == false && rs.Field<string>("delimiter") != string.Empty)
                       || (rs.Field<bool>("forEachRow") == true && rs.Field<string>("delimiter") == string.Empty)
           );
   ```

---

**UPD:**

name_column (varchar45)/строка

delimiter (varchar4)/строка

delimiter_column (int)/число

out_in_block (int)/число

forEachRow (tinyint1)/булевое

[image: Рабочая таблица]

Comment: Приложите описание таблиц, используемых в запросах, легче будет понять вопрос.

Comment: Привел описание полей, таблица одна собранная из нескольких. Сами таблицы и их назначение тут не играют роли. Мне не хватает знаний чтобы,правильно сформировать запрос к таблице.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем очевидно, что тут за источник данных, но в LINQ есть метод Except https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx, который призван исключить одинаковые элементы из последовательности.

```
var vnytrblock = dtSettings.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<int>("out_in_block") == 1)
    .Except(    dtSettings.AsEnumerable()
.Where(
    r =>
        r.Field<bool>("forEachRow") == false && r.Field<string>("delimiter") == string.Empty &&
       (r.Field<int>("out_in_block") == 1 || r.Field<int>("out_in_block") == 2)));
```

Как-то так это все должно выглядеть.

Comment: Идеально, всё верно. Я про Except не знал. Спасибо.